# Lightbox plugin and Jquery ui slider are not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>BootStrap | Nitin</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Jquery -->

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>  

    <link href="jquery/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- lightbox plugin js -->
    <script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>



    <!-- Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/testcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- custom stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/lightbox.min.updated.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .prod-store-logo
        {
            width: 80px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        .prod-image {
            width: inherit;
            height: 130px; 
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-top: 25px;
        }
        .prod-rating {
            color: black;
            height: 20px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .ui-slider-range { background: #ef2929; }
        .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #ef2929; }


    </style>


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <script>


$(function() {

  var outputspanmin = $("#minprice");
  var outputspanmax = $("#maxprice");
  var sliderElement = $("#slider-range");


  sliderElement.slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 10000,
  values: [ 300,1500],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      outputspanmin.html(ui.values[0]);
      outputspanmax.html(ui.values[1]);
 } ,
 stop : function (event , ui){

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'AjaxRemote.php',
                data: {'minprice': ui.values[0], 'maxprice': ui.values[1] ,
                <?php 
                if(!empty($brand))
                    {
                            echo '\'brand\':"' . $brand.'"';
                    }
                    if(!empty($category))
                    {
                            echo '\'category\':"' . $category.'"';
                    }

                ?>
                },

                success: function(data)
                      {     
                      // alert(data);
                         $('#filtering').html(data);                             

                     }
           });




 }

 });

 outputspanmin.html(sliderElement.slider('values',0));
 outputspanmax.html(sliderElement.slider('values',1));


});












    </script>




</head>
```

In above code i have used Jquery ui slider.
It is working fine. every thing was working until i added LIGHTBOX plugin which displays pop over image.
i have added .js file of Light box in head.
But now i am not able to see Jquery Ui slider. like wise i have changed places of light box .js script element but , sometimes jquery ui slider is visible but then lightbox plugin dont work , if one works other not.....
I know it is something related to placing of Jquery and js file  sequence..Please help

Comment: i didnt get you... Please Explain

Comment: Please add your HTML, CSS & Js in https://jsfiddle.net/ , save it and provide the URL. So it is easy to know what is going on in your code